# .php contact form not working

Tags: php, html

I can't get my .php contact form to work.

It loads the email_sent.php; however, the information never goes to the email specified. Are my variables named wrong or am I missing part of the function code?

```html
<?php
//if "email" variable is filled out, send email
  if (isset($_REQUEST['email']))  {
  
  //Email information
  $admin_email = "rogue_04_06@yahoo.com";
  $name = $_REQUEST['name']
  $email = $_REQUEST['email'];
  $subject = $_REQUEST['subject'];
  $messsage = $_REQUEST['message'];
  
  //send email
  mail($admin_email, $name, "$subject", $message, "From:" . $email);
  
  //Email response
  echo "Your information has been submitted. Thank you for contacting us!.";
  }
  
  //if "email" variable is not filled out, display the form
  else  {
?>

<form id="Contact Form" class="two" method="POST" action="email_sent.php">
<fieldset>
  <legend>E-mail Us</legend>
<p>Enter your information below along with your questions and/or suggestions.</p>

  <label>
    Name
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="John Smith">
 <span id="name_validation" class="error_message"></span>
  </label>

  <label>
    E-Mail
    <input type="email" name="email"placeholder="address@domain.com">
 <span id="email_validation" class="error_message"></span>
  </label>

<div>
<label>Subject</label>
 <div class="styled-select">
  <select name="subject">
 <option value="Option1">Question</option>
 <option value="Options2">Suggestion</option>
 <option value="Option3">Free Trial</option>
  </select>
 </div>
</div>

<label>Message</label>
<textarea name="message" id="message" placeholder="Type message"></textarea>

<button name="submit">
 <strong>SEND</strong>
</button>
</fieldset>

</form>

<?php
  }
?>
```

Comment: You should be more specific and use `$_POST` or `$_GET` instead of `$_REQUEST`.
http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php

Comment: Does the `mail()` line get executed at all?  What value does it return?

Comment: Have you installed a smtp server for your local test?

Comment: There is no execution at all. The email is never sent.

Comment: i'm unaware of any smtp

Answer (score 1):

Take care on this, the `;` is missing:

```
$name = $_REQUEST['name']
```

It seems you forgot close with (;).

```
$name = $_REQUEST['name'];
```

The second point is that you don't have a **SMTP server** installed, instead use the `mail()` function, I recomend use this library [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/), is more secure.